# How to make a form "reload"?

Tags: c#, winforms

After opening a WinForm I want to have a button that "reloads" the form. I want to make the Load Event run again.

Is that a way? Thanks!

Comment: Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: Do you want to reset the form to the startup state? Or just run the `Form_Load` run another time? Do note that running `Form_Load` again won't necessarily reset the form.

Comment: If you want to reload the entire form (or at least its controls, not the variables or code), remove all controls and call `InitializeComponent()` and then manually raise the `Load` event.

Comment: @MasterXD I want to run Form_Load again

Comment: @walkman Instead of calling `Form_Load` again, it's better to put code of `Form_Load` in another method like `void LoadData(){...}` and then call `LoadData();` wherever you need, including in `Form_Load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call it again like this:

```
Form1_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Just remember to use your own form's name

I hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks exactly what i wanted

Comment: @walkman Just glad to help